# Is there any way to handle errors in libxml sax parsing?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I have to  use libxml in my c++ code, for some reason and my program is parsing xml files with sax method.Is there any way to handle errors or exceptions in parsing?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own error handler like this :

```
static void my_error(void *user_data, const char *msg, ...) {
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, msg);
    g_logv("XML", G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL, msg, args);
    va_end(args);
}

static void my_fatalError(void *user_data, const char *msg, ...) {
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, msg);
    g_logv("XML", G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, msg, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

(example from [here](http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html#errors))

And register them using [`xmlSetGenericErrorFunc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlSetGenericErrorFunc) and [`xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc).

Example of registration without context :

```
xmlSetGenericErrorFunc(NULL, my_fatalError);
```

Comment: Can you explain how to register handlers?

Comment: See my last edit for an example of how to register an error handler.